# No Wi-Fi Adapter Found. Usually fixed by reboot, but not this time

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, lenovo

I'm running **20.04.1 LTS**. Today, all of a sudden I lost connection to the internet and found that in my Wi-Fi settings it says **"No Wi-Fi Adapter Found"** and I can't see any networks. Usually I just reboot and it works again, but not this time.

I found that if I run

```
lshw -C network
```

the terminal shows me that my Wireless interface is disabled:

```
*-network DISABLED        
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Wireless-AC 9462
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   logical name: wlp0s20f3
   version: 00
   serial: 54:8d:5a:83:ee:1a
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:16 memory:b1318000-b131bfff
```

I have tried:

```
rfkill unblock all
sudo ip link set wlp0s20f3 up
```

If I run the command

```
lshw -C network
```

again I'll find that the 'DISABLED' is gone, great.

Also when I run

```
sudo iwlist wlp0s20f3 scan | grep ESSID
```

I'll see the names of Wi-Fi networks around me, also great. I would say that means that at least my Wi-Fi hardware isn't broken.

**BUT**, there are two problems:

**1. It's somehow temporary**

When I reboot, switch airplane mode on and off or run a command like

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

the interface becomes DISABLED again.

**2. The Wi-Fi settings menu still doesn't work**

I still get told "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" when I go to the settings.

**additional info:** I don't have a Wi-Fi On/Off button on my laptop (a Lenovo Thinkpad E14), only an airplane mode. I have also set the BIOS settings to default.

I would be really thankful if anyone could help me out!

Best regards!

Comment: On all of my 20.04 and 20.10 systems its systemd-networkd that looks after the networks.
I configure all of mine via netplan e.g. yaml config files in /etc/netplan/

Comment: does that mean you don't use the settings at all? I'm a bit of a linux noob, so forgive me if that's a dumb question. I did actually try netplan at some point during troubleshooting after I enabled the interface, but for some reason it didn't work. I'll try again. But this sounds like it won't change what I see in the settings, right?

Comment: Netplan is yet human friendly layer above the normal network methods have a look at this link.

https://ubuntu.com/blog/quick-and-easy-network-configuration-with-netplan

Comment: Sorry this one is better for WIFI..
https://itsfoss.com/connect-wifi-terminal-ubuntu/

Comment: You create tour /etc/netplan/66-wifi.yaml file

Then run

netplan generate
netplan apply

Comment: Is this a dual-boot with Windows? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled  When the wireless is *not* working, are there any clues here? `dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: simon, thanks for the resources!
chili, it's not a dual boot.
i get this output:
[    2.329664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.332308] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-hr-b0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    2.335975] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.335990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 65.3.35.22
[    2.335993] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.335994] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0

Comment: [    2.336282] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 55.d9698065.0 QuZ-a0-hr-b0-55.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.336477] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    2.463882] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX201 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    2.654684] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 54:8d:5a:83:ee:1a
[    2.669547] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlp0s20f3: renamed from wlan0
[12647.487530] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.

Comment: Your dmesg looks normal. Are you able to capture in a text file so that you can post it here the results of `dmesg | grep -e iwl -e wlp` when the wireless is *not* working?